# writing a Custom Database Servlet

Tags: java, database, xpages

I am curious to set up some services for a NSF by writing Custom Database Servlets as found in the presentation 'IBM Connect 2016: REST Services in Domino - Key to modern Web Applications'.

Unfortunately the sample code in the NSF is limited to display only the data from a view. So not a single doc or handling of other than get methods.

I found some more interesting code here https://github.com/edm00se/AnAppOfIceAndFire but then the samples here a more advanced so this does not help with quickly getting on the learning ladder.

Does anyone has a more simplified of a Custom Database Servlet with handles both collections and single documents with CRUD support?

Comment: Thanks for the blog post idea Patrick! I've been slowly cooking up a draft of a blog post that might help answer some of this. I'll see if I can get that moved along.

Answer (score 3):

My preferred option is to build from scratch in a plugin, for which reason I uploaded a starter plugin that uses OpenNTF Domino API onto [OpenNTF](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API%20Demo%20Servlet). Full documentation is available on the [OpenNTF Wiki](https://wiki.openntf.org/display/ODA/ODA+Demo+Servlet).

The usual plugin development environment is required - Eclipse, XPages SDK from OpenNTF, IBM Domino Update Site for Build Management from OpenNTF. OpenNTF Domino API may also need installing to compile (I'm not sure, I have the source code in Eclipse). If so, I can work with someone to resolve that and update the documentation accordingly.

If you're looking for a simpler approach within an NSF, SmartNSF on OpenNTF seems to be a good option for developers looking to get more quickly up-and-running. It's very new at the moment, so documentation is pending, and consequently reaching out to the project chef is recommended.

Stepping beyond Domino Designer may be more advanced, but future-proofs skills.

Comment: I fear I have no experience creating plug-ins inside eclipse. I think it would require some hands-on instructions for me.

Comment: @PatrickKwinten have a look here https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/1934D011E867500185257EF10064C5AA  for a series on creating plugins for xPages/Domino

Comment: Jesse's blog series is a great place to start w/ plugins on Domino.